# read_data_sets is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Instructions for updating

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, google-colaboratory

This is my code

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("/tmp/data/", one_hot = True)
```

and these are the warnings I am getting when I run it, I am using an online environment, Google Colab to run it

```
WARNING:tensorflow:From <ipython-input-2-0d6f173b16c0>:6: read_data_sets 
(from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.datasets.mnist) is deprecated and 
will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Please use alternatives such as official/mnist/dataset.py from 
tensorflow/models.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist- 
packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/datasets/mnist.py:260: 
maybe_download (from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.datasets.base) is 
deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Please write your own downloading logic.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist- 
packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/datasets/base.py:252: 
_internal_retry.<locals>.wrap.<locals>.wrapped_fn (from 
tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.datasets.base) is deprecated and will 
be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Please use urllib or similar directly.
Successfully downloaded train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz 9912422 bytes.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist- 
packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/datasets/mnist.py:262: 
extract_images (from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.datasets.mnist) is 
deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Please use tf.data to implement this functionality.
Extracting /tmp/data/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
Successfully downloaded train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz 28881 bytes.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist- 
packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/datasets/mnist.py:267: 
extract_labels (from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.datasets.mnist) is 
deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Please use tf.data to implement this functionality.
Extracting /tmp/data/train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz
```

any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: What is the issue exactly? It does include instructions to update your code

Comment: It literally says "Please use tf.data to implement this functionality."

Comment: Look at the answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51480927/how-to-download-mnist-in-tensorflow-v1-9

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Please use below code

```
import tensorflow as tf
#Sets the threshold for what messages will be logged.
old_v = tf.logging.get_verbosity()
# able to set the logging verbosity to either DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR, or FATAL. Here its ERROR
tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.ERROR)
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("/tmp/data/", one_hot = True)
#in the end
tf.logging.set_verbosity(old_v)
```

Comment: Usually it's better to explain a solution instead of just posting some rows of anonymous code. You can read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), and also [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers)

Comment: Are you serious?! Do you really think that hide a warning is a best solution?! Oh my...

Comment: Usually a warning has a reason to be there! Don't just hide it!

Comment: i am getting ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.examples' ; and I support the argument of not hiding warnings.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way now seems to be to use keras:

```
from tensorflow import keras


mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist(train_images, train_labels),(test_images, test_labels) = mnist.load_data()
```