# How to download MNIST in TensorFlow v1.9?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am following a TensorFlow Tutorial.
I have installed Tensorflow r1.9 in python 3.6

I have the fallowing import:

```
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
```

and i use it in the fallowing way:

```
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("mnist_data/", one_hot=True)
```

I get the fallowing warning/error:

```
read_data_sets (from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.datasets.mnist) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating: Please use alternatives such as official/mnist/dataset.py from tensorflow/models.

python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/datasets/mnist.py:260: maybe_download (from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.datasets.base) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. 

Instructions for updating:
Please write your own downloading logic.
```

what is the correct way to work with mnist in r1.9?

Answer (score 6):

Best way now is using the keras module in tensorflow:

```
from tensorflow import keras

mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist
(train_images, train_labels),(test_images, test_labels) = mnist.load_data()
```